# Visio "breaking" arrow

Tags: visio

Can anyone help me how to stop Visio doing what is in the left example (in the picture). If I put the above object not centered with the bellow object, the arrow is ok.

[image]

Comment: It's hard to know without looking at the shapes in the file. It seems like the connector is trying to route around some invisible object - I wonder if the "C" graphic has some large, transparent area around it? Also worth a try: right-click the connector and choose "reset".

Comment: Nah, there is no invisible object there, looks like there should be, but is not... The reset option is not available on connector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to right-click the connector and select `Straight Connector`.

[Screenshot from Visio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtbDO.png)

Note that I moved the document object to show the difference between a straight-line connector and a right-angle connector. In my case, I was getting a straight line with both connectors if I center the document object.

Answer (score 0):

First you can right click on the arrow and select "Straight Connector". If this is not working, then try the following.

You can add connector points to the below object wherever required so that the arrow can be straight vertically.

[image]

Click on X mark next to connector option, then hold the ctrl button and click on the object to place the connector end then connect the objects.
Hope this might solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try fiddling with the Layout & Routing settings.

Right-click the Page Tab, then go to:

**Page Setup > Layout and Routing > Routing**

There are a bunch of settings for the style of chart, but have an extra look at the **Style** and **Appearance** drop-downs.

These settings govern the default layout/routing settings for the page.

Some of this can also be set via: **Design > Layout > Re-layout Page** and **Design > Layout > Connectors**